# Expectation of a series of indicators function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm studying stochastic processes and in the chapter of simple random walk there's an example saying let
$\mu_b$ the mean number of visit of the state $b$, starting at $S_0=0$ and without returning in $0$.
The book said:
$\mu_b=\sum_n P(S_1\cdot...\cdot S_{n-1}\neq 0, S_n=b)$.

To understand this fact I'm thinking: let $X=$number of visit of the state $b$, starting at $S_0=0$ and without revisiting $0$.
$X=\sum_n I_\{S_1\cdot...\cdot S_{n-1}\neq 0, S_n=b\}$.

My problem is that i need some conditions to switch expectation with the symble of series.

Comment: Since the sum is of non-negative terms, Tonelli's theorem implies that you can evaluate its expectation by switching it with the sum (even if it's infinite)

Comment: Thank you so much!